# Fetching Output Parameters from a stored procedure using Eclipse link

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I am calling a stored procedure from JPA EclipseLink. Stored Procedure returns three output variables, One cursor type and other two types. I am able to get the value returned from cursor but not the other two values.

Here is the part of stored procedure(example):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 (
Variable1               IN VARCHAR2,
Variable12          IN VARCHAR2,
Variable13                      IN VARCHAR2,
Variable14                  IN VARCHAR2,
p_xml_result                OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
p_errorcode             OUT NUMBER,
p_errorMessage      OUT VARCHAR2)
    IS
        -- Declare variable
        ERRSQL                         VARCHAR2 (80);
        NOSTRAECCEZIONE    EXCEPTION;
        ERROR_ONE                 EXCEPTION;
        V_AREA                        VARCHAR2(40);

    BEGIN
SELECT AREA
              INTO V_AREA
              FROM Employee
             WHERE     Employee_CODE = P_EmployeeCode;

              OPEN p_xml_result FOR
              <Some query to get data>
              p_errorcode := 0;
                p_errorMessage := NULL;

EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                p_errorcode := 100;
            p_errorMessage := 'generic error';

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            p_errorcode := 102;
            p_errorMessage := SQLERRM;
```

Java Code:

```
StoredProcedureCall procCall = new StoredProcedureCall();
procCall.setProcedureName("getSpecialOffers");
procCall.addNamedArgument("Variable1","Variable1",String.class);
procCall.addNamedArgument("Variable2", "Variable12", String.class);
procCall.addNamedArgument("Variable13", "Variable13", String.class);

procCall.addNamedArgument("Variable14", "Variable14", String.class);
procCall.addNamedOutputArgument("p_xml_result", "p_xml_result", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
procCall.addNamedOutputArgument("p_errorcode", "p_errorcode", Integer.class);
procCall.addNamedOutputArgument("p_errorMessage", "p_errorMessage", String.class);

Session session = ((JpaEntityManager)_em).getActiveSession();
ValueReadQuery query = new ValueReadQuery();
query.setCall(procCall);
query.addArgument("Variable1");
query.addArgument("Variable12");
query.addArgument("Variable13");
query.addArgument("Variable14");

Vector parameters = new Vector();
parameters.addElement(Variable1);
parameters.addElement(Variable12);
parameters.addElement(Variable13);
parameters.addElement(Variable14);


Object qResult = null;

qResult = session.executeQuery(query,parameters);
Vector vec=(Vector) qResult;
ArrayRecord arrayrec =(ArrayRecord) vec.get(0);
```

p_xml_result returns four field, which I am able to fetch as arrayrec.get("VariableXYZ"). and arrayrec also has only those four variables present which are returned from cursor. But I want to access the value of p_errorcode in my code in all the conditions. Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output params by changing ValueReadQuery to DataReadQuery.